# Kripke Models - evaluating the meaning of $\Box\Box p$

Tags: logic, modal-logic

In Kripke models the evaluation of $x \vdash \Box p$ would be that every world reachable from $x$ satisfies $p$.

But how would the truth of $\Box\Box p$ be evaluated in Kripke models?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an unfortunate use of the word “reachable”, in that Kripke structures are graphs but “reachable” in a Kripke structure is not the same thing as “reachable” in a graph.  Let us avoid this confusion by saying that a state $y$ is a *successor* of state $x$ if there is a (directed) edge $(x,y)$ in the structure.

Now, the semantics of modal logic says that $\Box\varphi$ is true at state $x$ if, and only if, $\varphi$ is true at every successor of $x$. Informally, $\Box\varphi$ means, “$\varphi$ is true everywhere I can get to from here in one step.” So, to understand the meaning of $\Box\Box p$, just substitute $\Box p$ for $\varphi$:

- $\Box p$ is true at every successor
- $p$ is true at every successor of every successor.

In other words, $p$ is true everywhere I can get in two steps.  Note that this is not, in general, the same thing as $\Box p$, which means that $p$ is true after one step. Indeed, one can show that $(\Box \varphi)\rightarrow (\Box\Box\varphi)$ is a tautology in a particular Kripke frame if, and only if, the successor relation is transitive.

Note that, without assuming transitivity, basic modal logic with only $\Box$ and $\Diamond$ has no way of expressing “$\varphi$ is true everywhere that can be reached from here, in any number of steps” (i.e., the usual graph-theoretic meaning of “reachable”).

Comment: Okay, so would □□□p be saying "anywhere I can get to in 3 steps" and so on? [This Stanford article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#pagetopright) says that in S4, operators of the same kind can be replaced by one occurrence of that operator. But if a specific logic is not specified which interpretation of evaluating □□p is the most intuitive?

Comment: @David Richerby - the semantics of $\Box$ is [usually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic) "Always", not "Next", which your answer appears to be taking to account.

Comment: @Shaull [Kripke models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics) ≠ temporal logic

Comment: @Shaull The semantics of $\Box$ in modal logics is (as far as I'm aware), always exactly as I've stated it.

Comment: @Ethan S4 is precisely basic modal logic plus the requirement that the edge relation of the Kripke frame is reflexive and transitive. And it's that transitivity that means that $(\Box\cdots\Box \varphi)\leftrightarrow(\Box\varphi)$ holds (and similarly with diamonds).

Comment: @Gilles - I deleted my answer, although LTL can be (and is often) interpreted over Kripke structures, so the question made perfect sense also in temporal logic.